# Pick a random value from an array that is not equal to the current value

Tags: arrays, logic, processing

How do I compare the value of a variable to the contents of an array in processing? Basically I have an array of color values. And I have a variable that is the current color. How do I say: "On this key press: Go through this array of color values, and pick a random value that is NOT equal to the current color. Assign that value as the new current Color?"

```java
color[] colorArray  = {#000000,#FFC000,#E0FF00,#7EFF00};
color currentColor;
color randomColor;

void setup(){
    size(640,480);
    smooth();
    noStroke();
    currentColor = colorArray[0];
}

void draw(){
    background(currentColor);

}

void keyReleased(){
    if(key == 's'){
    println("currentColor: "+currentColor);
    for(int i =0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
      //println(colorArray[i]);
      if(currentColor != colorArray[i]){
        println(colorArray[i]);
        // what do i do here? Append to another array and loop through again?    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps index the colors and just change to a different index. Try the following code which works quite nicely in Processing:

```
color[] colorArray  = {#000000,#FFC000,#E0FF00,#7EFF00};
int currentColor;

void setup(){
    size(640,480);
    smooth();
    noStroke();
    currentColor = 0;
}
void draw(){
    background(colorArray[currentColor]);
}
void keyReleased(){
    if(key == 's'){
    println("currentColor: "+currentColor);
    int newColor = currentColor;
    while (newColor == currentColor)
      newColor=(int) random(colorArray.length);
    currentColor = newColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Indexes! I got so hung up on comparing the value inside the array, I didn't see that just comparing indexes was a solution. Thanks for helping me see that.

Comment: Additional Q: Do you have a suggestion on where to look / what direction to go, if I wanted to colour fade between two background colours?

Comment: Perhaps this discussion could help: [Fading the background](https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1262739926.html)

Answer (score 0):

I like James Dunn's answer, but just to add: this is exactly the type of thing a **do-while** loop is designed for.

A do-while executes some code at least one time, and then continues executing that code while a condition is true. In your case, you could choose a random color, and then keep repeating that action while the new color was the same as your old color.

Here's a little example:

```java
color[] colors = {#ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff};
color currentColor = colors[0];

void draw() {
  background(currentColor);
}

void mousePressed() {

  color newColor;

  do {
    newColor = colors[int(random(colors.length))];
  } while (newColor == currentColor);

  currentColor = newColor;
}
```